# extract value from spinner and use it to calculations -- NullPointerException

Tags: java, android

I want to use the "value" from the spinner.

When the user makes the choice i want to use that value in order to do some calculations.

My problem is :

1) How to get properly the value (item).I am using sth like  "item.MyOnItemSelectedListener ==0".

2) What the value should be?For example ,above i have ==0 .This means the first choice from the spinner list?

The code:

```
public class number_cores extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    ..
    final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

        ...
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 ....


 //spinner-drop_list
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this, R.array.init_or_final, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());
    }
...
public void cores_func(){
           ...
             double fcores=0;

             MyOnItemSelectedListener obj=new MyOnItemSelectedListener();

         if ( obj.getPosition()==0) fcores=initcores*Math.exp(-l*ttime);
         else if (obj.getPosition()==1) fcores=initcores/Math.exp(-l*ttime);

..}

 //spinner class

        public class MyOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

            private int position;
        public int getPosition() {return position;}

            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                View view, int pos, long id) {
                 position=pos;

            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView <?> parent) {
              // Do nothing.
            }
        }
```

Thanks!

Comment: tried spinner.getSelectedItem()??

Comment: The problem is how to use the item object i created in the MyOnItemSelectedListener .

Comment: int or string?.. u can use toString() for string or use Integer.parseInt  smthn like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now all you are doing is assigning the Object item the value of the selected item in the spinner. You aren't saving that value anywhere you can access it.

To fix this, in your OnItemSelectedListener save the selected value or position in a field. Access it through a getter method in your listener that returns the value. In the onItemSelected method you would set the value each time the user changes the spinner's value. In the Activity, access the saved value through the listener via the getter method.

Example:
If you wanted to get the position of the selected item, add `private int position;` and `public int getPosition() {return position;}` as a field and method (respectively) in the listener class, and in the onItemSelected method `position = pos;` to save the value. It is a similar idea to save the object if you want that. In your application, `listenerName.getPosition() == 0` would be true if the first thing in the list was the selected item, so you can do logic with it.

Comment: :I tried.I put inn the spinner class, "public int position" and then in "onItemSelected" i put "position=pos".Then, in my cores_func ,i do "if (spinner.position ==0)" but it says "cannot be resolved or is not a field"

Comment: :Now it gives me "the method getPosition() is undefined for the type Spinner".Thanks!

Comment: You call it on your listener, not your spinner. Sorry my mistake.

Comment: The thing you need to get out of this is that all of your info is stored in the listener, not the spinner. Save the info to your listener and access it through your listener. The spinner is for the user, the listener is for your code.

Comment: A NullPointerException can happen for a number of reasons. I would suggest that you put your MyOnItemSelectedLsitener as a field of your Activity (like your spinner) to access it from multiple methods (i.e. outside of onCreate, and in cores_func) and then assign it once in onCreate. Then set it to the spinner because your above code makes an anonymous listener (one you can't call) and then makes a new one called obj later.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7149/discussion-between-ajcodez-and-george)